# Load XML containing custom namespace

Tags: xml, powershell

Using PowerShell scripts to dynamically append XML tags.
In this case trying to add a custom ElasticSearch target for NLog (from [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch)).

```bsh
$source = '<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper">  </target>'
```

When converting `$source` to XML using

```bsh
[xml]$source
```

or

```bsh
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($source)
```

I get the following error

> Cannot convert value "<targetname="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper">  </target>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'xsi' is an undeclared prefix."

Any suggestions?

**Almost, but not quite there:**

I can use `ConvertTo-Xml $source -as Document` but the result doesn't use the `<target>` tag, it uses `<Object>`, which doesn't work in this case.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
<Objects>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could load the XML fragment as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783511/1630171):

```
$source = '<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"></target>'
$sreader = New-Object IO.StringReader $source
$xreader = New-Object Xml.XmlTextReader $sreader
$xreader.Namespaces = $false
$fragment = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$fragment.Load($xreader)
```

However, assuming that you want to import that fragment into another XML data structure at some point, doing so will probably lead to other problems (see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28857669/1630171)).

To work around this issue add a dummy root node with the proper namespace definition to your XML fragment:

```
$source = '<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper">  </target>'
[xml]$fragment = "<dummy xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>$source</dummy>"
```

That way you can import the node into another XML document like this (provided the other XML file also contains the proper namespace definition):

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\master.xml'

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$nsm.AddNamespace('xsi', $xml.NamespaceURI)

$node = $xml.ImportNode($fragment.DocumentElement.target, $true)

$targets = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//targets', $nsm)
$targets.AppendChild($node) | Out-Null
```