# Insert a new XML node after another node

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, selectsinglenode

I'm really struggling to manipulate some XML in PowerShell that I need to send back to a web service as a body. Could anyone help me get the XML laid out the way it needs to be please?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EdgeGateway>
<Configuration>
    <GatewayInterfaces>
        <GatewayInterface>
            <InterfaceType>uplink</InterfaceType>
            <SubnetParticipation>
                <Gateway>1.2.3.4</Gateway>
                <Netmask>255.255.255.240</Netmask>
                <IpAddress>1.2.3.5</IpAddress>
# Missing the IpRange XML section - defined below
                <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
            </SubnetParticipation>
            <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
        </GatewayInterface>
    </GatewayInterfaces>
</Configuration>
</EdgeGateway>
```

needs to become:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EdgeGateway>
<Configuration>
    <GatewayInterfaces>
        <GatewayInterface>
            <InterfaceType>uplink</InterfaceType>
            <SubnetParticipation>
                <Gateway>1.2.3.4</Gateway>
                <Netmask>255.255.255.240</Netmask>
                <IpAddress>1.2.3.5</IpAddress>
# New Content added here
                <IpRanges>
                    <IpRange>
                        <StartAddress>1.2.3.5</StartAddress>
                        <EndAddress>1.2.3.5</EndAddress>
                    <IpRange>
                </IpRanges>
 # End of new content
                <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
            </SubnetParticipation>
            <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
        </GatewayInterface>
    </GatewayInterfaces>
</Configuration>
</EdgeGateway>
```

So far I've been able to create new XML Nodes/Elements for the new content, but I cannot get it to be inserted at the correct place. I can get the `AppendChild()` method to work, but it puts the content after the `<UseForDefaultRoute>` section - not before.

I've tried to do `InsertBefore()` and `InsertAfter()`, but it just doesn't want to work.
Finally, when I do the `AppendChild()` approach, I also get a bit of extra text I wasn't expecting, something about xmlns?

```xml
<IpRanges xmlns=""><IpRange><StartAddress>1.2.3.5</StartAddress><EndAddress>1.2.3.5</EndAddress></IpRange></IpRanges>
```

This is what I managed to put together, bear in mind that it's broken :(

```bsh
# load XML file
[xml]$doc = $response

# create node <StartAddress>
$startNode = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'StartAddress', '')
$start = $doc.CreateTextNode('1.2.3.5')
$startNode.AppendChild($start) | Out-Null

# create node <EndAddress>
$endNode = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'EndAddress', '')
$end = $doc.CreateTextNode('1.2.3.5')
$endNode.AppendChild($end) | Out-Null

# create node <IpRange> and append child nodes <StartAddress> and     <EndAddress>
$ipRange = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'IpRange', '')
$ipRange.AppendChild($startNode) | Out-Null
$ipRange.AppendChild($endNode) | Out-Null

# create node <IpRanges> and append child nodes <IpRange>
$ipRanges = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'IpRanges', '')
$ipRanges.AppendChild($ipRange) | Out-Null

# append node <IpRanges> to node <SubnetParticipation>
$subnetParticpation = $doc.EdgeGateway.Configuration.GatewayInterfaces.GatewayInterface[1].SubnetParticipation.AppendChild($ipRanges)
```

...following advice from Ansgar, this is my attempt at using a namespace. (broken)

```
[xml]$fragment = "<dummy xmlns:xsi='http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5'><IpRanges>$($ipRanges.InnerXml)</IpRanges></dummy>"

# $fragment.InnerXml ..returns..
# <dummy xmlns:xsi="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5"><IpRanges><IpRange><StartAddress>185.39.247.98</StartAddress><EndAddress>185.39.247.98</EndAddress></IpRange></IpRanges></dummy>

# $body is the full XML Document I want to paste into
[xml]$xml = $body

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$nsm.AddNamespace('xsi', $xml.NamespaceURI)
$node = $xml.ImportNode($fragment.DocumentElement.IpRanges, $true)

$subnetPart = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//IpAddress[text()='185.39.247.98']", $nsm)
$subnetPart

# returns nothing
```

Comment: "Doesn't want to work" is an insufficient problem description. What exactly have you tried? And what exactly were the results of that attempt?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it above in the edits, I didn't want to post a massive question, so sorry I ended up leaving that part out.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the new node after some other node like this:

```bsh
$node = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//IpAddress[text()='1.2.3.5']")
$node.ParentNode.InsertAfter($ipRanges, $node)
```

Comment: Whenever I used the // notation, it failed to find the IpAddress node, dropping the // from the selection worked in ISE.

To make thing more confusing for me, the approach that worked in ISE (using SelectSingleNode) doesn't work (with or without //) in the real environment, I think it might be an object type issue.
$test = $body.SelectSingleNode("//IpAddress[text()='1.2.3.5']")
$test

...returns nothing

Comment: ...also, when I do a Get-Member on the parent node, I get the following
TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement#http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5#SubnetParticipation

Comment: @DavidHocking The code I posted works just fine with the sample XML you posted. If it doesn't work with your live data then your live data is different from your sample data. Please update your XML sample to resemble your live data more. Going out on a limb, I would suspect that you have namespaces in the original XML.

Comment: Thanks, I apologise, you are correct, I just tested the same in ISE and it's working fine - in fact, it's better searching for the IP I wanted, rather than hard-coding for the "second instance" of GatewayInterfaces, so thanks for that :)

Comment: I also believe you're correct with the namespaces issue, is that the bit that's showing after the type-name when I do Get-Member? - if so, can I convert or work with the other namespace somehow?

Comment: @DavidHocking You need a [namespace manager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40049718/1630171) for handling XML with namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've read (and tried to understand) the post you linked to. I've added the code I've hacked together from your post, but it's still not able to search within the original XML Doc for the SelectSingleNode.

Comment: Ignore the `ImportNode()`. You're not trying to import a node from a different XML document, are you? Please update your question with a representative sample of your input XML.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose, W3C-conformant language designed to transforming XML files to other XML, HTML, even text formats. PowerShell can call the built-in [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) class passing in arguments of source file, xslt script, and output file.

**XSLT** *(uses Identity Transform to copy as is and updates the SubnetParticipation node)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SubnetParticipation">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <IpRanges>
        <IpRange>
          <StartAddress>1.2.3.5</StartAddress>
          <EndAddress>1.2.3.5</EndAddress>
        </IpRange>
      </IpRanges>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PowerShell**

```
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output) {
    Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
    exit;
}

trap [Exception]{
    Write-Host $_.Exception;
}

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;

$xslt.Load($xsl);
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

Write-Host "generated" $output;
```

**Command Line** call *(or batch script call)*

```
Powershell.exe -File "C:\Path\To\PowerShell\Script.ps1"
 "C:\Path\To\Source.xml" "C:\Path\To\Transform.xsl" "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EdgeGateway>
  <Configuration>
    <GatewayInterfaces>
      <GatewayInterface>
        <InterfaceType>uplink</InterfaceType>
        <SubnetParticipation>
          <Gateway>1.2.3.4</Gateway>
          <Netmask>255.255.255.240</Netmask>
          <IpAddress>1.2.3.5</IpAddress>
          <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
          <IpRanges>
            <IpRange>
              <StartAddress>1.2.3.5</StartAddress>
              <EndAddress>1.2.3.5</EndAddress>
            </IpRange>
          </IpRanges>
        </SubnetParticipation>
        <UseForDefaultRoute>true</UseForDefaultRoute>
      </GatewayInterface>
    </GatewayInterfaces>
  </Configuration>
</EdgeGateway>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it *sounds* interesting, but as I want to do everything from within a script, I've tried to re-write what you posted. I'm guessing it doesn't work because the .load method is expecting to read an item from a filesystem? - I'm not sure how else to get it to load the XSL.

Comment: Doesn't your XML load externally? Do note XSL *is* a well-formed XML file and can be handled like any XML including read from embedded string. Ah...once again the awesome, recursive XSLT returns back to the vault unused, unappreciated, largely ignored. We tried though on PHP, Python, Java, now PowerShell boards!